# How To Build a web.config for a react app using azure + IISNode + express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express

I built my react app after following this tutorial
https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/
and https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/. I know i'm not publishing to Heroku because I'm using an azure web app service, but due to the structure of my project I use a proxy to have the backend and front end hosted at the same time. When I run my app on localhost everything works fine and my react routing works so I know it's not an issue with my code. I have checked my logs and my requests hit the correct endpoints, however, none of my front end renders due to 403's, 500's and 404's. I have pin pointed it to my web.config file and I have no clue what it should look like. Some information about which file's I'm trying to render are here

heres the github repo as well incase this can help
https://github.com/ecoulson/OverlakeASB

path to index.html: /client/public/index.html

path to frontend: /client

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "overlakeasb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js 3001",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.1",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
    "azure-keyvault": "^3.0.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "easy-rbac": "^3.1.0",
    "easy-session": "^2.0.1",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mssql-connection-string": "^0.1.0",
    "mysql": "github:mysqljs/mysql",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rc-dropdown": "^2.2.0",
    "rc-menu": "^7.2.6",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-animate-height": "^2.0.3",
    "react-contextmenu": "^2.9.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-transition": "^1.2.1",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.6.1",
    "tedious": "^2.6.3",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

This is my web.config as of now

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="/client/public/index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/client/public/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <tracing> 
            <traceFailedRequests> 
                <add path="*"> 
                    <traceAreas> 
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Security" verbosity="Verbose" /> 
                    </traceAreas> 
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="404.2" /> 
                </add> 
            </traceFailedRequests> 
        </tracing> 
    </system.webServer>
    <system.applicationHost>
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging  enabled="true" /> 
    </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding

```
<globalModules>
<add name="iisnode" image="<path-to-iisnode.dll>" />
</globalModules>
```